# Sort Item in ListView by Attribute Windows phone 8.1 RT

Tags: sorting, listview

I want Sort Item in ListView by Attribute. But It's not working.
I try

```
LView.OrderBy(p=>p.attribute);

List<Object> LVnew = LView.ItemsSource as List<Object>;
LVnew.Sort(Story.cmp_new);

public static int cmp_new(Story a, Story b)
    {
        return (Int16.Parse(a.storyID) > Int16.Parse(b.storyID)) ? 0 : 1;
    }
```

Help me Friend

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but if it can help somebody :
To sort list of objects you have to extends the object's class to `IComparable`
Then add this method in your class :

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    var second = obj as YourClass;
    return YourAttribute.CompareTo(second.YourAttribute);
}
```

Last, you just have to call `Sort` method on yout list like that :

```
List<YourClass> myList = ...
myList.Sort();
```